# MVVM with dynamic commands

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to create a class that is able to create dynamic commands where I can bind to. I have a highly dynamic application with plugins, where the developer creates the plugin only in the backend and controls all things from the backend. The frontend is created in a different "remote" application that has the backend as the DataContext. Here's an example (not the full example), only to show what I want to do:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding PressMe}">PressMe</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>


namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        TaskViewModel Model = new TaskViewModel();


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = Model;

            Model.AddCommand("PressMe", (o) => { Console.WriteLine("TEST"); });
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is, how do I create something like this, if the XAML needs "well-defined" or "known" properties on which the binding can look at.

I thought of some TaskViewModel and implements IExpando, but somehow the reflection is not performed when hooking into the IExpando methods. Are there other ways to do something like this.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: Your View should **not** know about your ViewModel, you're breaking the MVVM design pattern here. You should instead use your commands as **properties** of your ViewModel, instead of dynamically creating them.

Comment: @MikeEason I disagree. The View already "knows" the ViewModel from the very moment you wrote `{Binding Anything}`. Even though there is not a compile time coupling, there is still a coupling without which nothing will work.

Comment: Anyways, OP, you're just looking for an `ObservableCollection<ICommand>` and an `ItemsControl`

Comment: @HighCore That's just wrong. Its not coupling - at all. It is, in effect, an implicit contract. The View binds to "something", thereby forming a contract that it expects the DataContext to have that "something". It has no knowledge (coupling) to what the datacontext actually is. The ViewModel provides the implementation for that binding contract (or doesn't and the binding fails).

Comment: @MeirionHughes an implicit contract which must be satisfied in order for everything to work. If I create an interface, or, say, a WSDL for a SOAP web service, that's a *contract*, by definition. If any of the intervening parts does not respect the contract, then nothing will work. My point is that it is okay to couple the code behind to a specific ViewModel (or an interface if you like it better), just as it is okay to use `{Binding Anything}`.

Comment: @MikeEason That is simply not true. The View is bound the viewmodel, the viewmodel however should not have a reference to the view (where possible).

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: You are right in most cases, but when you come to the point where bindings are not possible anymore (e. g. KeyBindings) you somehow have to hook-in your viewmodel to the view.

Comment: @msedi That is why I said "Where Possible". I am aware of the limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, Items-based UIs in WPF are implemented using an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/), and leveraging [Data Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx), regardless of the visual appearance intended for each item, or the actual behavior of the underlying classes.

In this case, you're looking for a dynamic collection of Commands:

```
// This class is not fully implemented. Replace by your own DelegateCommand or
// Grab an ICommand implementation from any of the well known MVVM Frameworks out there.
// This only exists for the sake of the example.
public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action action;

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action();
    }

    public Command(string displayName, Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Command> Commands { get; private  set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Commands = new ObservableCollection<Command>();
    }

    // You will add commands at some point at runtime.
    public void AddSomeCommands()
    {
        Commands.Add(new Command("Command1", () => MessageBox.Show("This is Command1!")));
        Commands.Add(new Command("Command2", () => MessageBox.Show("This is Command2!!")));
        Commands.Add(new Command("Command3", () => MessageBox.Show("This is Command3!!!")));
        Commands.Add(new Command("Command4", () => MessageBox.Show("This is Command4!!!!")));
    }
}
```

Then you can create an ItemsControl which shows `Button`s for each Command item:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication22.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding}"
                        Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
                        Margin="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.AddSomeCommands();

        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you need to bind these commands to hotkeys, simply add a property to the Command:

```
public Key HotKey { get; set; }
```

and then add something like this in code behind:

```
foreach (var c in vm.Commands)
    this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(c, c.HotKey, ModifierKeys.None));
```

Comment: I see your point. The problem is that I cannot use some items collection, since the commands are not only used for buttons, but also for keyboard events. So I really need to have a way, where I can reference with a name. Indeed I could work with the ObservableCollection but I also need a way wo work with a name in the {Binding}.